# Error with replacer replace(/./g,'/') replaces all characters

Tags: javascript, regex

My code is like this:

```
var dd = '22.02.2024';
dd = dd.replace(/./g,'/');
console.log(dd);
```

The result:
"//////////"

instead of a result of:

"22/02/2024"

Please help me to solve my problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `dd = dd.replace(/\./g, '/');` to match a literal dot character, you need to escape it using a backslash

Comment: `.` = any character.  If you want a `.` then use `\.` - alternatively use `.replaceAll` which doesn't use a regular expression  [replaceAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I found the answer

```js
var dd = '22.02.2024';
dd = dd.replace(/\./g,'/');
console.log(dd);
```

outcome:
"22/02/2024"